# How to import element UI with vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, babeljs

Here is the full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/osmosis_drive_front

What I want to do is use [element UI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart) for my project. I follow this [quick guide](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart). There is a babelrc setting in it. I have difficult time to merge [my babelrc](https://github.com/kenpeter/osmosis_drive_front/blob/master/.babelrc) with this one below. Anyone know how to merge these two babelrc and make Element UI working with Vuejs?

My babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

Element UI babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ],
  "plugins": [["component", [
    {
      "libraryName": "element-ui",
      "styleLibraryName": "theme-default"
    }
  ]]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    ["component", [
        {
        "libraryName": "element-ui",
        "styleLibraryName": "theme-default"
        }
    ]]
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```